# Order Of Things

Tags: visual-c++

I have a sniffer in C++ where I'm getting the Source IP, Destination IP, Control Bit, and Sequence number.  I am also getting the IP header and then the TCP info.  I want to get the content type of the packets.  Do I need to reassemble the packets to do that?  Or can I use http request and respond to get the content type of the packets.  Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is no reason to give this a negative.  If your so smart wht=y don't you answer the question???

Answer (score 0):

There is no "content type". TCP will only provide an octet stream for the layer above TCP to interpret. If you are sniffing HTTP over TCP, you will have to assemble the packets, and parse the HTTP yourself.

Have you considered using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

**Update**

By assembling the TCP packets into the octet stream, you basically append the payload of the TCP packets into one big byte array. Make sure you pay attention to the sequence number of the TCP packets, because the packets may arrive *out of order*.

Parsing the HTTP content is much trickier. The first headers are always in ASCII. They specify the content type and content length. It's the content type part that is tricky. Stuff may be encoded in a variety of encoding techniques, and they may be enveloped with yet another encoding technique (zip stream, SSL, etc).

- TCP RFC: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc793.html
- HTTP 1.1 RFC: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

It might be a good idea to see how both Wireshark and [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) does it. I'm not sure if WinPcap contains filters and decoders for HTTP (basically bringing you the content of the HTTP) or not. At any rate, it might be worth checking out the code.

Comment: Ok, can't use wireshark. I am sniffing http over TCP.  How do I assemble the packets? Any examples out there? How do I parse the http then?  Sorry, I'm new to this. Thank you